# According to the Catholic Church about Matthew 5:18-19?

Tags: gospel-of-matthew

> Matthew 5:18
>  For truly I tell you, until heaven and earth
>   disappear, not the smallest letter, not the least stroke of a pen,
>   will by any means disappear from the Law until **everything is
>   accomplished.**

1. what happen to the Law after "everything is accomplished" ? (the end of the world)

> Matthew 5:19
>  Therefore anyone who sets aside one of the least of
>   these commands and teaches others accordingly will be called least in
>   the kingdom of heaven, but whoever practices and teaches these
>   commands will be called great in the kingdom of heaven

If I interpret the sentence above to my own language, the meaning become like this : *either (A) the one who sets aside one of the least of the law and teaches others accordingly or (B) the one who practices and teaches the law, both goes to heaven. The difference is their status in heaven, A will be called the least - B will be called the great.*

Since I feel strange the interpretation if in my mother language, so I would like to know :

2. what does it mean actually the sentence in verse 19 ?

Thank you.